# multi-core usage, biased towards core 2?

Tags: 14.04, performance, cpu, htop

I have 4 cores in my system. Core 2 is frequently showing 100% usage in htop. Meanwhile Core 1,3,4 show something around 5% most of the time.

Is this normal? Is there a way to better distribute Core 2's load to the other cores and is that even desireable?

Comment: In order to say it's 'biased' to me implies that this is a consistent behavior (i.e. across reboots, etc), is that the case? Also, what type of CPU are we talking about? I'll say that on my quad i7 Ivy Bridge (8 logical cores), I see load balancing quite frequently in gnome-system-montitor. If one process is taking a lot of CPU time, it will often change cores every 5 seconds or so -- probably in order to help distribute heat across the die more evenly.

Comment: It looks like it definitely jumps around between CPUs, but is most likely to be seen on CPU2 for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, it can be normal. Depends on how much management the OS does. The two big tools to impact this are

- **taskset** which can direct what CPU a process can use
- setting the [IRQ affinity](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/IRQ-affinity.txt) of your pci devices

IRQ affinity is easy to fix. Do some IO, watch /proc/interrupts and if you see MSI-foo all on the same CPU then distribute them. You usually want to service IRQs on the "real cores" since they are the fastest. Once you have that figured out, write a script to commit that to system start and you're done.

Processes are a pain because they can migrate between CPUs. To "do it right" you really need to setup cgroups for the processes in question. Or... you take the lazy way out and make a wrapper script for program X that calls taskset ... _X.

Measure your before an after performance with a benchmark like fio or all your tweaking is for nothing. If you can't measure your changes you don't know what they're worth.

For example I have a 24 CPU, 2  numa node system here that has a storage device which will create a MSI interrupt for each CPU... and then bind them all to CPU 0 :-p. Spreading the IRQ affinity across the first 12 cores **quadrupled** the IO throughput recorded by fio. But this system actually has lots of bandwidth, the typical desktop does not.

Good luck. Performance work is fun, ... and hard :)

Comment: Another thing he might try is enabling the intel_pstate driver if it's an Intel processor. This can be done by adding "intel_pstate=enable" within the quotes of the line that starts with GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT in /etc/default/grub. Since Linux uses power scheduling for SMP systems, that might help. After the change is made run `sudo update-grub` and reboot.

Comment: I think It may have indeed been IRQ related so far. I tried some stuff with my video card and ended up seeing that X was taking up a huge amount of CPU time on one process. Another comment related to that suggested IRQ work. After a reboot, which I figure redistributed things, it seems to be working much more consistently.